# How to add claim to user dynamically?

Tags: asp.net, cookies, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I want to save some small info (say, user's device id) about the user, after or during sign-in. This data is dynamic, and I'd like the lookup to be very fast (without database hit), as I need it in many controllers. I tried adding it to user's claims like this:

`((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).AddClaim(new Claim("UserDeviceId", userDeviceId));`

to subsequently retrieve it like this: `User.FindFirstValue("UserDeviceId")` inside any controller. But it seems that the data is not persisted between requests! It returns NULL on another HTTP request.

I use standard SingInManager.PasswordSignIn() to sign the user in. I don't have claim store at all - I don't use default Identity EF implementation, I supply my own stores (IUserStore, IUserPasswordStore, and IUserRoleStore implementations). But even if I did, this data is dynamic and should not be persisted to / retrieved from a storage at all. The data is available upon sign in (basically client app sends hardware id).

As I understand, the dynamically added claim gets wiped out because it is never injected into the cookie, when I add it to `User.Identity` it just adds to in-memory instance, which gets overwritten by the cookie at next request. (or at least that's my best guess).

Is there any solution to this problem? I'd really like to avoid setting up Session mechanism, all I need is a *single* small value persisted across the requests, and even though strictly speaking it might not fully qualify as a "user claim", it is (conceptually) very close - it is a device id the user is currently connected from.

I use `User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)` in my controllers to get userId without any performance impact, and it is *very* convenient. It's setup by Identity itself obviously. I'd like to have similar mechanism for another identifier, preferably without rewriting half of Asp.Net Identity :) Is that doable? If not, what's my best alternative (besides setting up Session storage or supplying the value in every request)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Store data in cookie with asp.net core identity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39555810/store-data-in-cookie-with-asp-net-core-identity)

Answer (score 0):

After modifying the `ClaimsPrincipal` you will need call `HttpContext.SignInAsync(ClaimsPrincipal modified)` once again to update the session cookie.